# go mod checksum mismatch

Tags: go, go-modules

Thus far I'm the only developer on my team that can replicate this issue for the below package.

To correct the mismatch I've tried:

- go clean -modcache
- removing related entries in `.mod` `.sum` files
- entirely removing `.mod` and `.sum` files
- entirely removed the vendor directly
- uninstalling golang and purging all things go on my machine
- reinstalling latest version of go

```
> go get go.temporal.io/sdk@v1.10.0
go: downloading go.temporal.io/sdk v1.10.0
go get: go.temporal.io/sdk@v1.10.0: verifying module: checksum mismatch
    downloaded: h1:t0t/mtBxetBZUhvLB2mE2g7lgZcJDRAf1OPkV63+CfM=
    sum.golang.org: h1:JfzXWB+/EcDcC6poz6/k0dc57qas+Es1LMcIXEvP8IA=
```

I can install other versions just fine, just not `v1.10.0`. Does anyone have any suggestions or ideas on how to fix this?

EDIT:

As a work around I've added this package to GOPRIVATE which will exclude it from the checksum mismatch.

```
export GOPRIVATE="go.temporal.io"
```

Comment: What is your host OS?

Comment: @GariSingh Mac OS (big sur)

Answer (score 4):

Generally this occurs when the maintainer of the module attempts to move an existing tag from one commit to another. That isn't allowed: the Go [checksum database](https://golang.org/ref/mod#checksum-database) stores a permanent, irrevocable checksum the first time it encounters a new module version, and that checksum is used to verify that the module hasn't been tampered with for previous downloads.

If there is a severe problem with a given release, that release can be [retracted](https://golang.org/ref/mod#go-mod-file-retract) and a new patch issued. However, the new patch must have its own unique version (generally the same version *with the patch number increased by one*).

The proper fix here is to abandon `v1.10.0` and get the upstream to tag a new release.